# Calling a function with named arguments in a hosted application

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

So I am hosting IronPython in my C# application.  IronPhyton is used to implement a DSL for users. The DSL syntax should be something like this:

```
Ping(Message = "testOne1")
```

The hosting code looks like:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var scope = engine.CreateScope();

Action<string> ping = (message) => Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());            
scope.SetVariable("Ping", ping);
var script = @"
Ping(Message = ""testOne1"")
";
engine.Execute(script, scope);
```

But this does not work because `Action<string>` does not keep name of the argument. Calling it without the parameter name works as expected:

```
Ping("testOne1")
```

How do I store a function and call it with named arguments?

Comment: Try using `obj` for the name instead.  That's the name of the variable  in the delegate type.

Comment: `obj` does not look well for user's DSL :). Actually if there is no way to specify name of the argument, if will just use `Ping("testOne1")` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use named arguments you'll have to define the method statically. For example, I'll just put all DSL operations into an `Operations` static class.

```
public static class Operations {
  public static void Ping(string Message) {
    Console.WriteLine(Message);
  }
}
```

Then named arguments will work:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var scope = engine.CreateScope();

// Load the assembly where the operations are defined.
engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Import the operations modules, settings their names as desired.
engine.Execute(@"
from Operations import Ping
", scope);

// Now named arguments will work...
var script = @"
Ping(Message = ""Ping!"")
";

engine.Execute(script, scope);
```

Now if I could give you some advise; I'd prefer to implement the actual Python API in Python, and have that call back into my .NET code as needed. For example, instead of having the "operations" defined in C#, you'd have an `Operations.py` file which defines your Python DSL:

```
# Get access to your .NET API
import clr
clr.AddReference("MyAPI")
import MyAPI

# Define the Ping call to call into your .NET API
def Ping(Message):
  MyAPI.Ping(Message)
```

And your hosting code doesn't need to change at all.

Both are valid solutions, but the last one lets you iterate on your DSL easily.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the parameter is defined by the name provided in the delegate type.  In the case of [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx), the parameter name is `obj`.

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(
    T obj
)
```

`obj` should work for you.  Are you sure it isn't working?  It works for me.

In an IronPython project I have a library:

```cs
namespace TestLibrary
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static readonly Action<string> WriteLine =
            msg => Console.WriteLine(msg);

        // the same works if I do this instead
        //public static readonly Action<string> WriteLine = Console.WriteLine;
    }
}
```

And this works:

```py
from TestLibrary import Test

#Test.WriteLine(msg='foo') # error 
Test.WriteLine(obj='foo') # works
```

---

Hosted, same deal:

```cs
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();

Action<string> writeLine = msg => Console.WriteLine(msg);
// or even
//Action<string> writeLine = Console.WriteLine;
scope.writeLine = writeLine;

//engine.Execute("writeLine(msg='foo')", scope); // error
engine.Execute("writeLine(obj='foo')", scope); // works
```

Comment: Seems I was not clear enough. But name `Message` is only concern I have. My goal was exactly `Message` not `obj` or something else.

Comment: Thank you for you response anyway.

Comment: Oh so you _needed_ it to be `Message`.  Defining a method as Jimmy states is really the best thing you can do.  Though if you're open to this, you could define a new delegate with the appropriate names as an alternative.

Comment: I ended with second solution form Jimmy. Thank you for your help guys.